# Update table in SQL to have same value for duplicates, but different for unique values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, sql-update

I have the following SQL select statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    t3.*, t2.ItemPathwayGUID
FROM 
    SearchComplianceBuildCodeCat t1
INNER JOIN 
    SearchProductComplianceDraft t2 ON t1.SearchComplianceBuildCodeCatID = t2.SearchComplianceBuildCodeCatID
INNER JOIN 
    SearchComplianceBuildCodeCat t3 ON t1.SearchComplianceBuildCodeCatID_Parent = t3.SearchComplianceBuildCodeCatID
WHERE
    t1.SearchComplianceBuildCodeCatLevel = 3
    AND t1.Visible = 1
    AND t3.Visible = 1
```

This returns 29 rows of 1000+ rows. Currently, `t2.ItemPathwayGUID` is set to null as it is a newly added column. I want the value of the column to equal `NEWID()`. However, this value needs to be the same for rows that are identical.

For example:

| rowA | rowB | rowC | ItemPathwayGUID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | A1 | T4 | 7FD6073F-7747-4BD9-838A-3789235D2749 |
| 123 | A1 | T4 | 7FD6073F-7747-4BD9-838A-3789235D2749 |
| ABC | B3 | G2 | D7F906BF-66D1-450F-9E4B-61447CF91517 |
| 123 | A1 | T4 | 7FD6073F-7747-4BD9-838A-3789235D2749 |
| 321 | F0 | U6 | 60993525-3153-4AA0-8D82-8D61E024E043 |

- Rows 1,2,4 should be updated to have the same `ItemPathwayGUID`
- Rows 3 and 5 should be updated to have their own unique id

I have tried updating on select, however this seems to be updating every row to have a new guid rather than the id for duplicate rows, result in the select distinct command returning all 1000+ rows rather than the 29 that I desire.

Is this possible?

Comment: Update everything at first, then update duplicates with min id :) [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/G49bBMLG)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `MERGE` statement, with a function call, like this:

```
MERGE INTO w_uuid t USING(                 
  SELECT DISTINCT
    rowA
  , rowB
  , rowC
  FROM w_uuid
) s ON s.rowA = t.rowA
   AND s.rowB = t.rowB
   AND s.rowC = t.rowC
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
  SET ItemPathwayGUID = NEWID()
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an updatable CTE with a window function for this

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
      minID = MIN(NEWID()) OVER (PARTITION BY rowA, rowB, rowC)
    FROM YourTable
)
UPDATE cte
SET ItemPathwayGUID = minID;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/ENG6LRj5)

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you asked for, but could consider HASHBYTES as an alternative, where you're able to pass in your grouping columns as the input

```
declare @T TABLE(rowA varchar(10), rowB varchar(10), rowC varchar(10))
insert @t (rowA, rowB, rowC) values ('123','A1', 'T4'), ('123','A1', 'T4'), ('ABC','B3', 'G2'), ('123','A1', 'T4'), ('321','F0', 'U6')


select *, HASHBYTES('MD5', CONCAT(rowA, rowB, rowC))
from @t
```

Which provides

```
rowA       rowB       rowC       
---------- ---------- ---------- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
123        A1         T4         0x9ECAE1224D8688AE5C82C7C1C4985283
123        A1         T4         0x9ECAE1224D8688AE5C82C7C1C4985283
ABC        B3         G2         0x855E6FB33057F2EEF3EC0C550C051944
123        A1         T4         0x9ECAE1224D8688AE5C82C7C1C4985283
321        F0         U6         0xEE4D0B4A65E4EAB2C0AC7D3654D4C680
```